# Magento: need to export items from order to file

Tags: php, magento, export, orders, items

I have custom observer.php file, that create xml file after the order is created. there are all informations about invoice and shipping adresses, but I need to export items too. I tryed more styles to make it work, but still nothing work for me. what I have to add to observer.php to include all items informations?

```
<?php

class JULEC_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    public function exportObjednavky(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $orderIds = $observer->getOrderIds();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($orderIds); $i++) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIds[$i]);
            $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
            $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();   
            $fileContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                 <mrpEnvelope>
                  <body>
                    <mrpRequest>
                      <request command="IMPEO0" requestId="' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '">   
                      </request>
                      <data>
                        <params>
                          <paramvalue name="cisloSkladu">1</paramvalue>
                          <paramvalue name="stredisko">0</paramvalue>
                          <paramvalue name="cisloZakazky">0</paramvalue>
                        </params>
                        <objednavka formaUhrady="Dobierka" puvodniCislo="' . $order->getIncrementId() . '" datum="' . date("Y-m-d") . '" cenySDPH="F">
                          <mena kod="EUR" kurz="1" mnozstvi="1"/>
                          <adresa id="A' . $order->getIncrementId() . '" ulice="' . implode(' ', $billing->getStreet()) . '" mesto="' . $billing->getCity() . '" psc="' . $billing->getPostcode() . '">
                            <firma nazev="' . $billing->getLastname() . ' ' . $billing->getFirstname() . '" ico="X' . $order->getIncrementId() . '" dic=""/>
                            <osoba jmeno="' . $billing->getCompany() . '" prijmeni=""/>
                            <email>' . $billing->getEmail() . '</email>
                            <tel>' . $billing->getTelephone() . '</tel>
                          </adresa>';

            $sameAddress = $this->compareAddresses($billing, $shipping);
            if(!$sameAddress) {     
                $fileContent .= '
                          <adresa_dod id="" ulice="' . implode(' ', $shipping->getStreet()) . '" mesto="' . $shipping->getCity() . '" psc="' . $shipping->getPostcode() . '">
                            <firma nazev="' . $shipping->getLastname() . ' ' . $shipping->getFirstname() . '" ico="X' . $order->getIncrementId() . '" dic=""/>
                            <osoba jmeno="' . $shipping->getCompany() . '" prijmeni=""/>
                            <email>' . $shipping->getEmail() . '</email>
                            <tel>' . $shipping->getTelephone() . '</tel>
                          </adresa_dod>
                ';
            }

                 //need to get here list of items with its values  //

            $fileContent .= '<ITEMS><item =" ???SKU???   "text="   ???  ITEM NAME ???   "price="  ??? ITEM  PRICE ????  "qty=" ???  ITEM QTY ???  "tax=" ??? ITEM TAX RATE ??? " /></ITEMS>
                        </objednavka>
                      </data>
                    </mrpRequest>
                  </body>  
                </mrpEnvelope>

            ';

            file_put_contents('var/export_objednavky/' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '-' . $order->getIncrementId() . '.xml', $fileContent);

        }
    }

    public function compareAddresses($address1, $address2) {
        if (!is_null($address1) && !is_null($address2)) {
            if ($address1->getFirstname() != $address2->getFirstname())
                return false;

            if ($address1->getLastname() != $address2->getLastname())
                return false;

            if ($address1->getCompany() != $address2->getCompany())
                return false;

            if (implode(' ', $address1->getStreet()) != implode(' ', $address2->getStreet()))
                return false;

            if ($address1->getCountryId() != $address2->getCountryId())
                return false;

            if ($address1->getPostcode() != $address2->getPostcode())
                return false;

            if ($address1->getCity() != $address2->getCity())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you can try something like:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
  $itemSku = $item->getSku();
  $itemName = $item->getName();
  $itemPrice = $item->getPrice()
  /* etc */
}
```